# meaning of HR for interaction

Tags: statistics

I run a cox hazard ratio model for interaction and get the following result

```
VAR1                1.50    [0.84, 2.67]    0.001
VAR2                1.70    [0.98, 0.99]    0.001
VAR1:VAR2           0.35    [0.12, 0.45]    0.30
```

Is there any meaning to the HR of the VAR1:VAR?
Does that mean that when combined the risk for the event deminishes?

Sorry if this is a basic one.
Thanks!

Comment: what is VAR1 and VAR2? are they categorical or continuous?

Comment: Hi! Categorical.

in 2 unique cases var1 is categorical and var 2 is continues

Comment: @StupidWolf     Hi! Categorical. in 2 unique cases var1 is categorical and var 2 is continues

Comment: you can see the answer below.. too long to comment. again very hard to know how this is modeled from just a table. If the below makes sense then good. Otherwise you ought to provide the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we check the definition for [cox hazard model](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-proportional-hazards-model) :

> The Cox model is expressed by the hazard function denoted by h(t).
> Briefly, the hazard function can be interpreted as the risk of dying
> at time t. It can be estimated as follow:
>
> h(t)=h0(t)×exp(b1x1+b2x2+...+bpxp)
>
> where,
>
> t represents the survival time h(t) is the hazard function determined
> by a set of p covariates (x1,x2,...,xp) the coefficients
> (b1,b2,...,bp) measure the impact (i.e., the effect size) of
> covariates. the term h0 is called the baseline hazard. It corresponds
> to the value of the hazard if all the xi are equal to zero (the
> quantity exp(0) equals 1). The ‘t’ in h(t) reminds us that the hazard
> may vary over time.

So in your question, I suppose these are the raw coefficients returned by the model. If var2 the coefficients indicate the increase in risk per unit of var2. Since Var1 is categorical, it indicates how the risk changes as it goes from 1 category to the other. It is unclear what is ran to obtain these results, so let's say if there are two categories A and B, A is modeled as the reference and B would reflect how the odds change in B compared to A.

The interaction term var1:var2 would be the change in coefficent of var2 in the presence or absence of var1. Again unclear how var1 is modeled, so using my example above, var2 will be the slope in A and var2:var1 indicates the change in var2 when in B.